# Vue JS: Build command `npm run build` is not able to generate `index.html`

Tags: vue.js, npm

When I'm running `npm run build`, it is not creating `index.html` in the `dist/` directory. The reason I need `index.html` is that I want to deploy my Vue project to AWS EC2 (`/var/www/html/`). What to do to generate this `index.html`?

My `dist/` directory structure after running `npm run build`:

[image]

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "proto",
  "description": "Prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@melmacaluso/vue-modal": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.15.1-sr.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-fusioncharts": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

The build command output:

```
$ npm run build

> proto@1.0.0 build C:\Users\john\Documents\VUE\dummy_prototype_1
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules
```

Comment: depoy in /var/www/html/ index.html file and folder /dist (with bundles), and be sure that in index.html there is a <script> line that loads bundle

Comment: Thanks for the information. Since I've already shared the dist/ folder, can you give more idea of the <script> line? Pardon me, I'm new to this.

Comment: <script src="./dist/your_web.min.bundle.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`, scroll down then add the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) plugin into `module.exports.plugins` as **@Michal Levy** suggested.

**Updated**:
For the error (`webpack.js:348 throw err; TypeError: Cannot read property 'make' of undefined`), one possible reason is version issue. The solution is downgrade (uninstall then install） html-webpack-plugin to **3.2.0**.

**Below is new configuration for plugins:**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    // below is the plugin you need to add
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/index.html'), // the path where is the `index.html` generated.
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
      },
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: After copying the above code to `webpack.config.js`, when I'm running `npm run build`, I'm getting this error: `C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:348` `throw err;` `TypeError: Cannot read property 'make' of undefined`

Comment: Did you install the plugin? `npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: Downgrade (uninstall then install） html-webpack-plugin to 3.2.0, then try again.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. You are either a magician or a genius.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)

It will automatically create (new or from template you provide) `index.html` in the dist folder and inject any necessary `<script>` (for js bundles) or `<link>` (for extracted CSS) tags

As it seems you already have `index.html` template, use `template` option - see the [docs](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options)